# RESTful API - авторизация по JWT токену

Tags: php, веб-программирование, rest, авторизация, jwt

**Здравствуйте.**

Имеется проект на PHP, к которому необходимо привязать JWT авторизацию. Как организовать логику работы?

Мы получаем зашифрованный JWT с данными пользователя, что с ним делать дальше? Поместить в localstorage браузера нет возможности, так как это PHP. Добавить в сессии? То же не вариант, так как у API сервера и frontend-сервера могут быть разные домена и сессия в этом случаи не сработает.

Хотелось бы узнать мнение более опытных людей, которые сталкивались, либо решали подобные вопросы, какие есть способы авторизации по JWT? Либо же, как хранить Json Web Token у пользователя и при необходимости получать на API сервер и аунтефицировать пользователя?

Comment: *что с ним делать дальше* - отдать токен для последующих авторизованных запросов, или так не подходит?

Comment: наверное все зависит от времени действия токена(и от того чей сервер свой или чужой вам вернул токен). если он например как у гуглового FCM сроком действия один час, то можно его и в памяти сервера хранить и юзеру вернуть в виде куки и хранить гдето в переменных приложения до срока истечения. а если он более длительный то тут уже будут другие требования, опять же получить новый ключ от пользователя дело не долгое, т.к. сертификат-то у него должен храниться где-то постоянно.